# Need for modification of the javascript countdown code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please i have a JavaScript countdown timer code that i got from stackoverflow that is a solution to my countdown timer project. this existing code counts down time from 30minutes down to 1 and start over again. and it gives the same count result to every user at the same time. But my challenge with the code is that i was not able to modify it in other to be able to regulate the count duration, because i want it to countdown from 2minutes to 0 and start over again continually,but not exceeding 2minutes. Please i need someone that will copy this code and run it a see if you can regulate the duration and help me with the solution. thanks in anticipation.

The code is as follows:

```
setInterval(function() {
function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
var x = document.getElementById("timer");
var d = new Date();
var s = (d.getSeconds());
var m = (d.getMinutes());
var a = addZero(30 - m);
var b = addZero(60 - m);
var c = (60 - s);
var z = "<span style='color:red;font-size:50px;'>" + "Break" + "</span>";
var v = "<span style='color:black;font-size:24px;'>" + "Break" + "</span>";

if (m > 30) {
    y = b;
}
else if (m < 30) {
    y = a;
}
if (y < 2 && c < 15) {
    q = z;
}
else {
    q = v;
}

var t = y + (":" + addZero(c) + " Till Station " + (q));
x.innerHTML = t;
}, 250);



<div align="center" id="timer" style='color:black;font-size:24px;' ></div>
```

Comment: That code is bad. Variable names should be descriptive, not one-letter `a`, `b`, `c`... And variables should be defined explicitly, not implicitly global, like `y` or `q`. Better program it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you presented deserves a few remarks:

- Variable names should be descriptive, not one-letter a, b, c...
- Variables should be defined explicitly, not implicitly global, like now happens for `y` and `q`
- When `m` is 30, then `y` does not get a value... this cannot be right.
- If that last point would be corrected, then the logic for setting `z` would pose a new problem.
- Styling should be done as much as possible via CSS classes, not via `style` attribute settings.

Here is how you could do it. You can set the first two constants to your liking:

```js
// Maximum number of seconds for the timer (e.g. 120 = 2 minutes)
const MAX_SECS = 120;
// Number of seconds below which text gets highlighted
const WARN_SECS = 15;
// DOM
const spanMinutes = document.getElementById("min");
const spanSeconds = document.getElementById("sec");
const spanWarning = document.getElementById("break");
// For formatting numbers with 2 digits
const twoDigits = i => i.toString().padStart(2, 0);

setInterval(() => {
    let seconds = MAX_SECS - Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) % MAX_SECS;
    spanMinutes.textContent = twoDigits(Math.floor(seconds / 60))
    spanSeconds.textContent = twoDigits(seconds % 60);
    spanWarning.classList.toggle("warn", seconds < WARN_SECS);
}, 250);
```

```css
#timer {
   text-align: center; 
   font-size: 24px;
}
.warn {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"><span id="min">00</span>:<span id="sec">00</span>
     till station <span id="break">breaks down</break>
</div>
```